# Does Googlebot see duplicated content when content is shown in a loop with JavaScript?

Tags: seo, googlebot, duplicate-content

One of the projects I have recently developed uses SwiperJS slider with loop option set to true. It generates duplicated slides which makes sense. Since each slide represents an article the SEO guy warned me that the crawler will see the duplicated content asking to handle it properly.

Came across [this article](https://www.merkleinc.com/blog/how-well-does-google-crawl-javascript-pretty-darn-well) explaining that google crawlers actually does see the generated content. Can't find any related info to break this down. Asking if anyone faced similar issue and have any solution.

So the questions are does it really a problem for the SEO having slides duplicated and is there any solution to keep the slider looped infinitely hiding the duplicated content for the crawlers.